# How to inject a service class into a Spec class with Play framework

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

I'm trying to write tests for a scala-play application and I got stuck because I can't inject MyService into my class spec (example code below).

//------THE SERVICE I WANT TO INJECT -----------///

```
class MyService@Inject()(ws: WSClient,
                         config: Config,
                         myData1DAO: MyData1DAO,
                         myData2DAO: MyData2DAO,
                         myData3DAO: MyData3DAO,
                         myData4DAO: MyData4DAO,
                         myData5DAO: MyData5DAO,
                         myData6DAO: MyData6DAO)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
        def methodIWantToCallInTests = ???
}
```

////------------MY TEST SPEC-------------------/////

```
class MyTestSpec Inject()(myService: MyService) extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar { 
// DOESNT WORK :(
//


  "MyService" should {
    "make something good" in {

        new MyService( .., .., ..,).methodIWantToCallInTests  // TOO LONG :(

    }
  }
}
```

Trying to inject MyService as shown in the code doesn't work (and it's even a dumb try probably). The only other thing I was thinking about is to make the "new" of MyService.

Please help even with just a link or book I can find the answer in. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any possibility to manage test suites themselves with dependency injection. (`class MyTestSpec Inject()(myService: MyService)` suggests you are trying that.

But you can easily obtain the service instance from the application. Here is an example for Guice:

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneServerPerSuite

class MyTestSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneServerPerSuite {

  "MyService" should {
    "make something good" in {

      val service = app.injector.instanceOf[MyService]
      service.methodIWantToCallInTests

    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating `new` Instance of `MyService` only, unless you have `implicit` of your `DAO` objects and you can directly Inject the class into your testspec.